# IP address of the username who uses sftp connection in unix

Tags: sftp

We have SFTP connection in unix location.How can I find the IP address of the particular username with whom we have SFTP connection to share the files?

Comment: Have you inspected `sftpd` logs?

Comment: using `w -f` should show you what protocol is being used and what is being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question but there are certain facts about SFTP connection:

1.First for sftp connection ssh must enabled.

2.If ssh enable then you must login with the

```
ssh user@hostname/ip
```

, if you don't know ip then use command

```
ifconfig
```

after login with ssh.

3.If you know the hostname then you can find out the IP with the command

```
ping "hostname"
```

Comment: Welcomme to U&L, I fixed presentation. however IPs are not related to username, but rather to hostname.